# How to create analog for such C# StreamProxyApplication function in C++ using Boost library?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, boost, translation

I haven't done work in C/C++ for a little bit and was just wondering if any one can help me with porting this .Net C# code into C++ using Boost library (Boost.Asio)

So I have one function:

```
 private const int bufferSize = 8192;

/// <summary>
/// The entry point of the application.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">The input arguments of the application. The first argument should be a valid http address of the source server. The second argument should be a valid http address of the destination server.</param>
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Check the amount of the arguments.
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.Write("Not enough arguments. Expected 2, recieved " + args.Length + ".");
        return;
    }

    // Try to get the source server URI.
    Uri sourceUri;
    try
    {
        sourceUri = new Uri(args[0]);
    }
    catch (UriFormatException)
    {
        Console.Write("Invalid source server address.");
        return;
    }

    // Try to get the destination server URI.
    Uri destinationUri;
    try
    {
        destinationUri = new Uri(args[1]);
    }
    catch (UriFormatException)
    {
        Console.Write("Invalid destination server address.");
        return;
    }

    // Try to connect to the source server.
    Stream sourceStream;
    try
    {
        sourceStream = WebRequest.Create(sourceUri).GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.Write("Cannot connect to the source server. Details: " + exception.Message);
        return;
    }

    // Try to connect to the destination server.
    NetworkStream destinationStream;
    try
    {
        destinationStream = new TcpClient(destinationUri.Host, destinationUri.Port).GetStream();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.Write("Cannot connect to the destination server. Details: " + exception.Message);
        return;
    }

    // Start redirecting the data.
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    do
    {
        try
        {
            read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Write("An error occurred while receiving data from the source server. Details: " + exception.Message);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            destinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Write("An error occurred while sending data to the destination server. Details: " + exception.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
    while (read > 0);

    Console.Write("All data redirected.");
}
```

How to create its simple\general analog in C++?

main Idea here is to transmit live streaming data from one broadcasticg source to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be simple at all to port to C++.  What takes one line in C# requires a whole bunch of infrastructure in C++, because you have the entire .Net framework at your fingertips in the CLR.  I believe boost::asio is a lower-level interface than you need for this.  If you do have to do this in C++ then there is stuff in [ATL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x74c73yy(v=VS.80).aspx/) or [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382925(VS.85).aspx/) which could prove useful.

Is there any way you can encapsulate the code from here that you need in a small C# assembly, and call into it from C++ using COM interop?

Comment: I'm curious about the anonymous belated downvote of an accepted answer. Care to explain what you did not like?